# PHP составление класса

Tags: php, ооп

Имею базовый класс вывода комментариев, и хотел бы узнать, валидный ли это код или нет. В кратком, перенесу его структуру.

```
class Comments {
public $data;

function get() {
 return $this->data = $db->getAll("SELECT * FROM comments");
}

function show() {
 for($i = 0; $i < count($this->data) $i++) {
  $result .= '<div class"comment">'.$this->data[$i]['text'].'</div>
}

}
```

В месте вывода я делаю:

```
$comments = new Comments;
$comments->get();
$content = $comments->show();
```

Корректная ли это структура построения?

Answer (score 5):

### Правильная ли архитектура с точки зрения ООП? - Безусловно нет.

Класс вы написали, и в целом это будет работать, но принципы проектирования нарушены.

Есть такие принципы называются [SOLID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)), так вот в соответствии с ними нужно привести архитектуру в порядок. Один принципов вы безусловно нарушили.

**Принцип единственной обязанности**

*Для каждого класса должно быть определено единственное назначение. Все ресурсы, необходимые для его осуществления, должны быть инкапсулированы в этот класс и подчинены только этой задаче.*

Если рассматривать даже минимальные требования к архитектуре, то у вас класс занимается двумя вещами - это получение данных из хранилища и вывод данных, а еще обращается к глобальной переменной.

**Также**, c точки зрения качества кода, у вас модификаторы не объявлены для функций, для data вообще стоит публичный модификатор доступа, что позволяет мне внести в него изменения о которых можно забыть и долго искать. В данном случае, хорошо бы чтобы такие свойства были закрыты для получения и изменения извне без соответствующих методов.

### Рефакторинг

Пишем абстрактный класс для [DAO](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Access_Object)

```
abstract class Dao 
{
   protected $db;

   public function __construct(YourDatabaseAbstractClass $db) 
   {
      $this->db = $db;
   }
   public function setDb(YourDatabaseAbstractClass $db) 
   {
     $this->db = $db;
   }
   public function getDb() 
   {
      return $this->db;
   }
}
```

Пишем класс для работы с получением данных на основе абстрактного класса:

```
class ComentsDao extends Dao {
    public function getAll() : array
    {
         return $db->getAll("SELECT * FROM comments");
    }
}
```

Пишем интерфейс для HTML сущности:

```
interface HtmlElement {
    public function getHtml();
}
```

Пишем класс на основе интерфейса:

```
class CommentElement implements HtmlElement {

     protected $data;

     public function __construct(array $data) 
     {
          $this->data = $data;
     }

     public function getHtml() 
     {
          $result = '';
          for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->data); $i++) 
          {
            $result .= '<div class"comment">'.$this->data[$i]['text'].'</div>';
          }
          return $result;
     }
}
```

Это один из простых способов рефакторинга, в идеале из DAO должен возвращаться массив обьектов **Comment**, который должен быть заранее определен. Передача ассоциативных массивов в функции в подобном решении - не лучший выход.

**А если проще, то воспользуйтесь ORM и шаблонизаторами, где велосипеды которые вы собрались писать уже реализованы за вас.**